# Downcast Instantiated UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to declare my `UITableViewCell` out of scope, as shown below, in order to drastically thin this code out.

However, the following implementation returns an error (where there are the arrows), yelling:

`Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'friendButton'`

I was expecting the force downcast in `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to work.

I would like to delcare my `UITableViewCell` out of scope in order to have all `configureCell` methods and `return` statements out of the control flow.

```
let resultCell = userResults[indexPath.row]

var cell: UITableViewCell!

    if friends.contains({$0.parseObjectId == resultCell.parseObjectId}) {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FriendCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FriendCell
------->cell.friendButton.tag = indexPath.row
------->cell.configureCell(resultCell)
        return cell
    } else if requestedFriends.contains({$0.parseObjectId == resultCell.parseObjectId}) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RequestedFriendCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RequestedFriendCell
        cell.friendButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.configureCell(resultCell)
        return cell
    } else if incomingFriendRequests.contains({$0.objectId == resultCell.parseObjectId}) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AcceptFriendCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AcceptFriendCell
        cell.friendButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.configureCell(resultCell)
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AddFriendCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AddFriendCell
        cell.friendButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.configureCell(resultCell)
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: @ozgur Relax. As I said, the implementation returns an error. `friendshipButton` is fixed.

Comment: Do all of your cells have a common superclass besides `UITableViewCell`? Do all of the objects in the arrays have a common superclass?

Comment: @Paulw11 No, the cells are immediate children of `UITableViewCell`, however the arrays are all of the same type

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare the variable `cell` of type `UITableViewCell` and then use it as `FriendCell`.

Remove the `var cell = ...` in line 3 and add `let` at the beginning of line 6 to make THAT `cell` a local variable.

Also your variable names are confusing which unnecessarily complicates things. There's no reason to have two variables `cell` and `friendCell`. `friendCell` should likely be called just `friend`. Same for `resultCell`.

Comment: I agree. Why go to the trouble of declaring the cell *outside* the if and then still having multiple `return` statements?

Comment: @Paulw11 REad the question, I want to reduce the amount of code = single return statement

Comment: As long as there's isn't anything else you want to do with the cell other than what you're already doing you can't make it much shorter by moving the cell variables one scope higher. You'll most likely make it longer.

Comment: Ok, but you haven't shown a single return statement, so that isn't clear. I would create a variable in the `if` statement as per this answer and then assign *that* to `cell` so that you can have a single `return`, but you are still going to have the same number of lines. I don't see much wrong with the code you have, except there is no reason to search by `objectId`, you can just search by the PFObject directly and using cell tags for indexPath is a bit icky; better to declare a proper delegate protocol if that is what you need

Comment: The problem is the arrays whose elements I'm comparing `resultCell` with are not arrays of `PFObject`s. Could you elaborate on the delegate protocol ? @Paulw11

Comment: Ok. As far as the delegate goes, I am assuming that the reason you are storing the row in the tag is so that later when some action occurs on the cell (a button tap?) you know which row it corresponded to. If you have some sort of delegate protocol from the cell back to your view controller that passes the cell, you viewController can use indexPathForCell to get the indexPath

Comment: You would have the touchUpInside action handler in the cell and have it call some delegate method like `someCellDidTapButton:cell` in your view controller

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes I've been looking for something like this! could you point me to a code example?

Comment: @Paulw11 So I'd essentially define the protocol in the cell, then make the `ViewController` conform to it (next to the class declaration)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96852/discussion-between-paulw11-and-eric-johnson).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the var `cell` is defined as being of type `UITableViewCell`.

Even though you are dequeueing/force-casting a `FriendCell` and assigning it, the var `cell` itself is still of type `UITableViewCell` (*not* `FriendCell`).

---

If you still want to keep the shared `cell` variable outside the `if` checks (and have only one return statement, not many), you will have to use the code suggested by @ZHZ above:

```
(cell as! FriendCell).friendButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

...to configure the properties specific to the `FriendCell` subclass.

---

**Edit:** The alternative is to define subclass-specific variables inside each `if` block and have one `return` statement for each.

Comment: But then I still have to call `configureCell` within the control flow, correct?

Comment: Anything that is `FriendCell`-exclusive will habe to be called using the `(cell as! FriendCell)` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You need to type cast your cell to the child cell, otherwise child specific functions won't be detected by parent. This is primary concept of OOP. You have to explicitly typecast into child class to access its functions. What you should do is:

```
var cell: UITableViewCell!; 

if friends.contains({$0.parseObjectId == resultCell.parseObjectId}) {

var friendcell : FriendCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FriendCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FriendCell
        let friendCell = friends[indexPath.row]
        friendcell.friendButton.tag = indexPath.row
        friendcell.configureCell(friendCell)
        cell = friendcell;
    } 

    ---------

    return cell;
```

Comment: `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` can not return `nil` (at least in swift). The compiler won't allow that code.

Answer (score 1):

All your cell subclasses share the `friendButton` property and the `configureCell` methods.

If they don't share a superclass, they probably should, let's call that superclass `GenericCell`

You can declare `cell` like this:

```
var cell: GenericCell!
```

That `GenericCell` class should implement `configureCell` and have the `friendButton` property, and then you can cast the cell as `GenericCell` and call those methods without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FriendCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
let friendCell = friends[indexPath.row]
(cell as! FriendCell).friendButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

Comment: The error OP is getting has nothing to do with that.